# internal/modules/cjs/loader:1042 throw err;

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am getting a follwing error.

```
 code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
```

[image: database_error]

1. Deleted the node_modules directory
2. Deleted the package-lock.json file
3. Run npm install
4. Also Run npm run dev

Answer (score 0):

Same error on my side!
The four processes don't solve anything!:
1. Deleted the node_modules directory
2. Deleted the package-lock.json file
3. Run npm install
4. Also Run npm run dev
Consider, I have VS code on Ubuntu 23.045.
I finally uninstalled mysql and installed it again. Now my db is connected!